# How to use as.numeric(levels(f)[f])

Tags: r, normalization

I was attempting an assignment and hit a problem with the dataset. As per the questions, we have to take the Duration, Amount, and Installment columns for analysis. I tried to normalize the data for these columns using scale() command, taking them into a seperate data frame. But, I get an error saying: 
Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

I explored further to find that the dataset may not be purely numeric, although at the sight of it, it seems that all three columns are numeric. I used the is.numeric() command and got the result:
is.numeric(new_dataset)
[1] FALSE

Having gone this far, now I am stuck at how to convert the non-numeric data into numeric type, without having to replace all the values manually. I found some stuff on "as.numeric(levels(f)[f])", but wasn't able to understand how to apply it. I am getting error:

> new_dataset_num<-as.numeric(levels(new_dataset[,1:3]))[new_dataset[,1:3]]
>   Error in as.numeric(levels(new_dataset[, 1:3]))[new_dataset[, 1:3]] : 
>   invalid subscript type 'list'

Can you please help out with this?

Comment: Hi VaibhavPant, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you add a tag onto your question so we know what language you're writing please? It'd help a great deal.

Comment: 'duration' and 'amount' sound like they would be numeric variables but 'installment'? are you sure this one is numeric? try `class()` or `str()` to see which of your variables is not numeric.

Comment: Hi I was able to work out the scaling problem using as.numeric() simply on the main variable. All 3 variables were actually not numeric and had to be converted.